# Match anchor tag with a specific href

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have a dashboard with a sidebar with navigation links where I highlight each link on the side once you go to the link. I match the link by doing this

```
$(function() {
    var item = $('.sidebar-menu a[href="' + location.href + '"]');

    item.parent().addClass('active');
});
```

But the problem is if you add an hash (#) to the address then it no longer matches the link. And I want it to match it regardless.

Currently it would match:

- mysite.com/students/companies

But it wouldn't match:

- mysite.com/students/companies#
- mysite.com/students/companies/subpage

I want it to match anything that includes "mysite.com/students/companies"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with

```
$('.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
  return location.href.indexOf(this.href)!=-1;
}).parent().addClass('active');

var item = $('.sidebar-menu a[href*="' + location.pathname + '"]');
```

Comment: But what if the pathname is "/students/companies/somethingelse"? I want "/students/companies" to match it

Comment: Still only matches for "/students/companies/"

Comment: I changed `this.href.indexOf(location.pathname)` to `location.href.indexOf(this.href)` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I think you got problem because your anchor  tag look something like that:

```
<a href='somethingelse.php'>Something Else</a>
```

I notice that you call parent div so.. you wrap your anchor tag by div or ul,li or something else..

What you can do simple add some extra data like 'data-user=''
so `<div data-user='companies'><a href='somethingelse.php'>Something Else</a></div>`

So now if somebody will be inside companies or something else just do the trick:

```
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = url_string.split('/')
var item = $('div[data-user='+url[3]+']).addClass('active');
```

That will work for webpage look like:
www.some.com/companies
and
www.some.com/companies/sometihng
even
www.some.com/companies/sometihng/more